# How to Refresh Multiple Text areas (with HTML content up to 4000 chars) in HTML-FORM on click of Button in FORM?

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, navigation

I'm storing Data in PHP Two dimentional Array . Sample Values in PHP ARRAY is mentioned below:

```
First Element in Array
ID = 1
QUES= <p>ABCD</p>
OPT_A = <p>A</p>
OPT_B = <p>B</p>

Second Element in Array
ID = 2
QUES= <p> TWOABCD </p>
OPT_A = <p>TWA </p>
OPT_B = <p>TWB</p>
```

I am displaying values of QUEST, OPT_A, OPT_B in TEXTAREA in a HTML FORM (using TinyMCE jquery plugin for displaying rich text). 
The Form has the following buttons : NEXT & PREVIOUS.

On click of NEXT, I want to get TEXT AREAS refeshed with data from next element in array for all values. 
As per search over internet, I can achieve the same using AJAX, but not sure, how to refresh data of multiple text areas at the same time on click of a button in HTML FORM. Also note data is stored in the form of HTML Tags (with max length upto 4000 chars).

Currently, I'm using a very old method, of refreshing entire page on click of button on a form. It's having lot of drawbacks, including when the page gets refreshed, momentarily the user sees HTML tags before the page is loaded completely.

Can you please suggest any reference for (fixing these two issues) :

1. Refreshing Data in Multiple Textares of a HTML-FORM on click of Button (inside HTML-FORM) using AJAX
2. Avoiding momentary display of HTML code in Text area
       before page is completely loaded.

Updated CODE is mentioned below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="id" type="hidden" name="id">
        <p>Question:</p>
        <p id="myInstance3" style="border: 1px solid #000;"><textarea id="quest" readonly></textarea></p>
        <p>Option A:</p>
        <textarea id="opt_a" ></textarea>
        <p>Option B:</p>
        <textarea id="opt_b" ></textarea>
        <p>
            <button id="previous">Previous</button>
            <button id="next">Next</button>
        </p>
    </form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var array = [{"id":1,"quest":"<p>ABC<\/p>","opt_a":"A","opt_b":"B"}, {"id":2,"quest":"<p>DEF<\/p>","opt_a":"1","opt_b":"2"}];
    var ArrayWalker = (function () {
        var _array = null,
            _index = 0,
            _walk  = function (step) {
                if (_array === null) {
                    throw 'Array is not initialized';
                }
                _index += step;
                if (_index < 0 || _index === _array.length) {
                    _index -= step;
                }
                return _array[_index];
            };
        return {
            init: function (array) {
                _array = array;
                _index = 0;
            },
            current: function () {
                return _walk(0);
            },
            next: function () {
                return _walk(1);
            },
            previous: function () {
                return _walk(-1);
            },
            index: function (seek) {
                if (seek !== undefined) {
                    _index = window.parseInt(seek);
                }
                return _index;
            }
        };
    })();

    function fillElements(data) {
        $('#id').val(data['id']);
        $('#quest').val(data['quest']);
        $('#opt_a').val(data['opt_a']);
        $('#opt_b').val(data['opt_b']);
    }

    ArrayWalker.init(array);
    fillElements(ArrayWalker.current());

    $('#previous').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fillElements(ArrayWalker.previous());
    });
    $('#next').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fillElements(ArrayWalker.next());
    });
</script>
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
          var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
          myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel');
          myNicEditor.addInstance('myInstance3');
     });
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using HTML5, you should not use closing slashes in tags like input. This is XHTML, not HTML5: `<input id="id" type="hidden" name="id" />`. This is HTML5, not XHTML: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: You are also missing a `<title></title>` tag which is invalid HTML

Comment: Thanks Dan, I've updated HTML as per comments. Still not able to get data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is based on traversing a given array that could be get via AJAX or directly on the page request.

You can *convert* your PHP array into a Javascript one by doing this:

```
// This is your given array
$array = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 1,
        'quest' => '<p>ABC</p>',
        'opt_a' => 'A',
        'opt_b' => 'B',
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 2,
        'quest' => '<p>DEF</p>',
        'opt_a' => '1',
        'opt_b' => '2',
    ),
);

// This is how you convert it to Javascript
echo 'var array = ', json_encode($array), ';';
```

Output:

```
var array = [{"id":1,"quest":"<p>ABC<\/p>","opt_a":"A","opt_b":"B"}, {"id":2,"quest":"<p>DEF<\/p>","opt_a":"1","opt_b":"2"}];
```

Now you need a Javascript object that can use that array in order to fill your `textarea` elements:

```
var ArrayWalker = (function () {
    var _array = null,
        _index = 0,
        _walk  = function (step) {
            if (_array === null) {
                throw 'Array is not initialized';
            }
            _index += step;
            if (_index < 0 || _index === _array.length) {
                _index -= step;
            }
            return _array[_index];
        };
    return {
        init: function (array) {
            _array = array;
            _index = 0;
        },
        current: function () {
            return _walk(0);
        },
        next: function () {
            return _walk(1);
        },
        previous: function () {
            return _walk(-1);
        },
        index: function (seek) {
            if (seek !== undefined) {
                _index = window.parseInt(seek);
            }
            return _index;
        }
    };
})();
```

Assuming this markup:

```
<form>
    <input id="id" type="hidden" name="id" />
    <p>Question:</p>
    <textarea id="quest"></textarea>
    <p>Option A:</p>
    <textarea id="opt_a"></textarea>
    <p>Option B:</p>
    <textarea id="opt_b"></textarea>
    <p>
        <button id="previous">Previous</button>
        <button id="next">Next</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

This function will fill the elements:

```
function fillElements(data) {
    $('#id').val(data['id']);
    $('#quest').val(data['quest']);
    $('#opt_a').val(data['opt_a']);
    $('#opt_b').val(data['opt_b']);
}
```

And finally you need to use your tools to get the job done:

```
ArrayWalker.init(array);
fillElements(ArrayWalker.current());

$('#previous').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fillElements(ArrayWalker.previous());
});
$('#next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fillElements(ArrayWalker.next());
});
```

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aYqTD/).

Comment: Thanks Jackflash for detail explanation, Let me try this today.

Comment: Hello Jackflash, I'm trying to understand answer provided by you by creating sample page, Somehow data is not getting populated & page is still getting refreshed. Sample code is updated in the question. I'm still trying to figure it out... please suggest, if you've any pointers.

Comment: @PawanMude You said you was using jQuery but it is not included in your code. Please paste `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` as your first script. Also, you should move all of your scripts just before `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: Hello Jackflash, as suggested I updated code, but somehow still data is not getting populated. Updated code is pasted in question.

Comment: @PawanMude If your are testing this locally, you should add `http:` to jQuery `script` `src` like this: `<script src="http://ajax.goo...`

Comment: I've updated code with Rich Text Editor ; it's still showing HTML Tags in in...any pointers to resolve same?

Comment: @PawanMude TinyMCE probably provides a method to set HTML code. Check the api docs and tell me back when you get it. I'll modify `fillElements()` function for you.